# I can't find/see my .plist folder that were saved using the Xcode simulator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode

I'm trying to screw around with the encoding files (doing a tutorial). Anyways, I trying to save a file called, "Checklists.plist" and can't find it in my app location:

**USERINFOSTUFF**/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/**APP NUMBER**/Library/Documentation/Checklists.plist

ALSO, the documentation folder in the library is doesn't exist according to terminal when I try to unhide it even though Xcode says that it does exist...

The bold is just to get rid of the jargon. Here's the code:

```
- (NSString *)documentsDirectory
{
    NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
    NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
    return documentsDirectory;
}

-(NSString *)dataFilePath
{
    return [[self documentsDirectory] stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"Checklists.plist"];
}

-(void)saveChecklistItems
{
    NSMutableData *data = [[NSMutableData alloc] init];
    NSKeyedArchiver *archiever = [[NSKeyedArchiver alloc] initForWritingWithMutableData:data];

    [archiever encodeObject:items forKey:@"ChecklistItems"];
    [archiever finishEncoding];
    [data writeToFile:[self dataFilePath] atomically:YES];
}
```

I got the paths using:

```
NSLog(@"Document is at: %@", [self documentsDirectory]);
NSLog(@"Data file path is at: %@", [self dataFilePath]);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentationDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

to this:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,  NSUserDomainMask, YES);
```

Comment: Nice catch. However I still can't visibly see the "Checklist.plist" folder in my documents path.

Comment: USERINFOSTUFF/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/7.0.3/Applications/APP NUMBER/Documents/Checklists.plist tried your code with NSDocumentDirectory and your file shows up. Note I wrote an NSArray object in "items" place.

Comment: Yes, I should've said items was an array, my bad. It shows up now. Thanks for taking the time to do this. +1